# DNS lookup is giving incorrect output

Tags: perl, dns

This is the code I am using. What is the problem with the code?
Moreover, how can I specify the timeout parameter? tcp_timeout does not seem to work.

```
sub resolve_dns()
{
    my $dns = $_[0];
    my $res   = Net::DNS::Resolver->new(

                nameservers => [qw(24.116.197.232)],
                recurse     => 0,
                debug       => 1,
                tcp_timeout => 3
                );
    my $query = $res->search($dns);

    if ($query) {
        foreach my $rr ($query->answer) {
            next unless $rr->type eq "A";
            print $rr->address, "\n";
        }
    } else {
        warn "query failed: ", $res->errorstring, "\n";
    }
}
```

This is the output I am getting.

```
Output

query failed: query timed out
;; search(www.youtube.com)
;; setting up an AF_INET() family type UDP socket
;; send_udp(24.116.197.232:53)
;; send_udp(24.116.197.232:53)
;; send_udp(24.116.197.232:53)
;; send_udp(24.116.197.232:53)
```

Comment: @Brian, So is this the problem with the nameserver? If I don't specify the nameserver, it works fine.

Comment: I would suspect so. You can verify that by trying it on the command line with nslookup or dig. It certainly times out for me. (Exactly - if you're using your default nameserver it works ... therefore, not a code issue)

Comment: Can you tell me how to specify a timeout parameter. If a nameserver is going to timeout, I don't want to wait more than 3 secs on that server. Please put that as an answer and I can accept that.

Comment: @cppcoder, I can see two other bugs in your code. First you tell Perl the sub takes no arguments (`sub resolve_dns()`), but it does take one argument (`my $dns = $_[0];`). That means you not only have an incorrect prototype, you specifically override if (by using `&`) for no reasons. Get rid of the `()` in the sub's declaration, and get rid of the `&` in the sub call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a timeout using:

```
$res->udp_timeout(3);
```

or, replace the specify it in the constructor.